# Oracle constraints lowercase

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, regexp-like

I have to make oracle constraints that checks if username is minimum 3 and maximum 10 lowercase letters.

I have used

```
constraint usernameSMALLCASE check (
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{10}$') or 
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{9}$') or
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{8}$') or 
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{7}$') or 
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{6}$') or
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{5}$') or 
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{4}$') or 
    REGEXP_Like(username,'^[a-z]{3}$')
)
```

However, it is not working.
Somehow, putting $ is causing problem. But I have to put $ to make sure end of the end of line char is also small case.

Comment: Please add sample data here which backs up your observations.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? What is the error you get? Or what are the values that are accepted but shouldn't? Or what are the values rejected but shouldn't? However, you can simplify the expression to: `check (regexp_like(username,'^[a-z]{3,10}$'))`

Comment: I just did the example for you (used the hint from @a_horse_with_no_name). Please use the dbfiddle to validate your question and add test results if any https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=336494bd56322cc17b34cd715c474b6b

Comment: "it is not working" is not helpful. Does it not enforce the requirement that the field be a sequence of lower-case letters from 3 to 10 characters long? Is there an error? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and tell us what happens. Thanks.

Comment: How is the USERNAME field defined? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and include this information in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What about special characters like "öäü" for example?

Answer (score 5):

Your code should work if your column is declared correctly.  But you can drastically simplify it:

```
constraint usernameSMALLCASE check ( REGEXP_Like(username, '^[a-z]{3,10}$') )
```

Obviously there are other methods besides regular expressions for handling this.  However, you have started down the regular expression route and it is simple enough using one.

If you insist on a fixed length column, you can express this as:

```
constraint usernameSMALLCASE check ( REGEXP_Like(username, '^[a-z]{3,10} *$') )
```

Comment: From OP's description and a little playing around it seems likely that his USERNAME field is defined as CHAR(10) instead of VARCHAR2(10), which explains why the `$` in the regular expression would cause his constraint to fail. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94c7fd895794f3f2ec4d48592769b8f0)

Comment: Class `[a-z]` is not fully reliable, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create constraint for

```
username = lower(username) and length(username) > 3
```

The max length you can enforce by data type

```
username VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL
```

Note, regular expression `^[a-z]{3,10}$` is not fully reliable, see [Character Class '[: :]' in Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG304)

A non-working example is this one:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = XSPANISH;

BEGIN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE('ch', '^[a-d]$') THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TRUE');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FALSE');
    END _IF;
END;
```

Returns `TRUE` (despite `h` is not between `a-d`) because `ch` in traditional Spanish is considered as **one** sorting character.

I think a 100% reliable constraint would be like this:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(TRANSLATE(username, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '**************************'), '^\*{3,10}$') 
   AND username NOT LIKE '%*%'
```

Comment: I upvoted but then realised not quite right: username '1234$%^' would pass this check.  But I am always attracted to regexp-free solutions!